# $\forall$ real sequence $\left(u_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}},\exists f$ analytic such that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, f(n)=u_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, analytic-functions

This might be a known result, but I haven't found anything so far.

Prove or disprove:

For any real sequence $\left(u_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, there is at least one analytic function $f$ such that $f$ coincides with $\left(u_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ on $\mathbb{N}$, i.e $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, f(n)=u_n$.

I haven't any clue as of how to proceed...

If this result happens to be false, then what about this weaker version :

For any real sequence $\left(u_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, there is at least one **smooth** function $f$ such that $f$ coincides with $\left(u_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ on $\mathbb{N}$, i.e $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, f(n)=u_n$.

I have no idea wether the first conjecture is true or false, but I am pretty sure the weaker one is true. For proving the weaker conjecture, I have thought about building a smooth function by doing "smooth junctions" between pieces of linear functions that would link the values taken by $\left(u_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Seems doable, albeit pretty messy.
But for the stronger conjecture, I don't think "analytic junctions" are always possible...

Comment: Hint: See if there exists an analytic function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f'(x) = \lim_{x\to 1^-} f'(x) = 0$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. That will solve the weaker version, but might enlighten the strong one as well.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious here, but...
Even if there is, it doesn't mean the junction will be analytic nor smooth, just analytic on $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{N}$ and $C^1$ on $\mathbb{N}$.
Even if there's not, that doesn't implies we can't find an analytic/smooth $f$ : it doesn't have to have nul derivatives on the junction points...

Comment: You're absolutely right, but, again, a solution that have the properties above would be easier to understand. But yes, it is no use for analytical case.

Comment: Something similar is an exercise in Ahlfors, Complex Analysis, page 196 in the second edition. Chapter 5 is called Series and Product Developments, the exercise is at the end of section 2.3.

Comment: This follows from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem